# Partial copy of table and insert values at same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, ssms

So this is going to be an odd question but I'm going to try and explain it as best as I can in order to assist anybody trying to help me here...

I am presented with a situation in which I am trying to copy data from one database to another to similar tables, however there is a slight difference which makes a world of difference.  `db1.table1` allows `null` values in `col3` and does in fact have a number of rows which have null values but `db2.table1` does not allow `null` values in `col3` but I still need to copy the values over.  Furthermore, `db1.table1.col3` is a `GUID` while `db2.table1.col3` is `VARCHAR` which is part of the issue.  If `db1.table1.col3` weren't of type `GUID` I was simply going to `UPDATE` the column with the text that I need to insert there that I am going to need in `db2.table1.col3`.

So, to summarize: I am looking for a way to 
    `INSERT INTO db2.table1 (col1, col2, col3...) SELECT col1, col2, col3... FROM db1.table1` but at places where col3 is null, I need to insert text/varchar so that it's not null.

Is there any simpler way to do this than building a temporary table that anybody knows of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use COALESCE or ISNULL with the replacement text that you want

for example `ISNULL(Col3, 'Sometext')`

for a GUID, you can use the NEWID() function since you can't insert regular text into a uniqueidentifier data type

The NEWID() function returns a GUID....for example

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

26C064EF-0AB6-4DBE-91B3-C2EE40DE7AD6

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what you mean by the last part about NEWID().  Could you give me an example if that's not asking too much?

Comment: Run this  `SELECT NEWID()`

Comment: Oh, so if I understand this correctly you're suggesting that I fill in db1.table1.col3 with the random NEWID to allow me to copy over, and then once its copied perform the UPDATE to insert the text I want?

Comment: WHat I am saying is that yuo can't update the column with anything but a uniqueidentifier datatype, if I understood correctly that is what it is, if it is a regular varchar(36) then you can update/insert anything that fits